Sphinx не генерирует страницу на русском языке
Разбираюсь со sphinx. Все делаю по инструкции. Но никак не могу добиться, чтобы отображался русский текст. В конфиге написано  language = 'ru'
Думаю, в сторону локализации, но кажется что это не совсем правильно. Исходный текст (текст в файле index) на русском,  переводить мне его не надо, мне его надо отобразить.
Подскажите, куда "копать".
Питон 3.6.3
Sphinx 7.3.7
P.S. я не программист, но страницу собрать надо :((

Пересохраните «исходный текст» в кодировке utf-8 например?

Спасибо за ответ!! Я уже тоже об этом думала. И поменяла кодировку- но не сработало и пересохраняла свой файл с другой кодировкой - не помогло.  А сработало вот что. Сделала файл rst с тремя произвольными словами внутри, сохранила в нужной кодировке сразу. Потом открыла, ненужный текст удалила, а свой вставила и сохранила.
